# How to deploy SpringMVC to heroku with postgres default data

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, heroku, appfuse

I have an appfuse app(Spring MVC + hibernate) I would like to deploy on heroku.

The app has already been pushed to heroku master and the app seems to be running but 
the postgres dev keeps complaining that tables do not exist.
(saying something like "relation 'table_name' does not exist")

In my dev environment, the dbunit-maven-plugin drops and creates the needed tables as well as populates the tables with sample datas defined in default-data.xml file but it doesn't seem to happen on heroku postgresql.

How do I make the default database schema to be created with the
default data populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old but came across it while searching for something else. I was able to resolve that error by adding 'schema=public' to my models.